# Stop keyboard from closing when Enter is pressed in EditText?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an EditText which has the singleLine attribute set to true. When I press Enter on the keyboard, the keyboard is hidden. Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: What should happen instead of hiding keyboard?

Comment: If the edittext is empty, i don't want it to close the keyboard. Just want it to say visible. This saves the user pressing the EditText to open the keyboard again.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using OnKeyListener which caused this problem. Switching to OnEditorActionListener stops the Keyboard from closing when pressing Enter and allows me to have full control of it.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //DO THINGS HERE
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help you

```
 youredittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) &&
             (keyCode           == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)   )
        {               
           // hide virtual keyboard
           InputMethodManager imm = 
              (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

when you press the enter key the inputMethodManager will show the keyboard, if needed.

hope this will solve your problem :)

edit:
if this will not work try use the event.getKeyCode() in the secend part of the if statment
edit II: sorry, i read it wrong, i fixed it now try this one.